# What is the meaning of "further down the agenda"?

Tags: word-usage

In this sentence:

> Some of the sensitive topics that have dominated xxx talks in the past now seem further down the agenda.

What is the meaning of "down the agenda" in this sentence?, What is the usage of "down"? Is it used as a verb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that it's less of a priority now.

This comes from *[agenda](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/agenda)* as in a list of things that need to be done, usually listed in order of importance/urgency. Things at the top of the agenda are more important than those at its bottom; when something is moved *down* the agenda, it's been de-prioritized.